# Determining the execution time of all statements in process of FPGA

Tags: fpga

I'm beginner studying FPGA. I'm confusing a problem.
I have code and the data type I use is fixed-point:

```js
process(clk)
  begin
   if(clk'EVENT and clk ='1') then
      r_amp := to_sfixed (amp,amp'HIGH,amp'LOW);
    r_Va  := resize (r_amp * to_sfixed(Va,0,-31),r_Va);
    r_Vb  := resize (r_amp * to_sfixed(Vb,0,-31),r_Vb);
    r_Vc  := resize (r_amp * to_sfixed(Vc,0,-31),r_Vc);
    V_alpha := resize(r_Va/(to_sfixed (2/3,4,-27)*Udc),V_alpha);
    V_beta  := resize(to_sfixed(0.57735026919,4,-27)*(r_Vb-r_Vc)/(to_sfixed (2/3,4,-27)*Udc),V_beta);
    tmp := resize(to_sfixed(0.57735026919,4,-27)*V_beta,tmp);
    z1x := resize(V_alpha - tmp,z1x);
    z1y := resize(to_sfixed (2,4,-27)*tmp,z1y);
    z2x := resize(z1x+z1y,z2x);
    z2y := resize(to_sfixed (-1,4,-27)*z1x,z2y);
    z3x := resize(z1y,z3x);
    z3y := resize(to_sfixed (-1,4,-27),z3y);
   end if;
   end process;
```

How to caculate the execution time of all statements in process? if all statements don't finish in 1 clock period, what will happen?
Thank for watching.

Comment: There are no declarations for any of your variable assignment targets. There are no signal assignments. Named objects whose value are not evaluated elsewhere would be deleted in synthesis as unused. Your code doesn't represent a [specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The delay of a path through multiple combinational expressions and intermediary objects post synthesis mapping can be evaluated (as in vendor static timing analysis, or generated mapped models with timing applied using SDF files for example).

Comment: I'm so sorry. Because my code is so long. I shortened the declaration of process. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You define the clock period in ns and the synt/PR-tools tries to place the logic so this time constraint is fulfilled. If it fails you will get a timing error.

If it is not finished within 1 clk the result is undefined.

Comment: Is the synt/PR-tools ISIM or modelsim?

Comment: @John modelsim has no required info. Delays can be estimated only after complete synthesis/placement/routing was done. modelsim has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Vlad Thank you so much.Do you know  if all statements don't finish in 1 clock period, what will happen in real system ?

Comment: @John, most likely you will get some garbage as output simply because correct values won't propagate fast enough. You can get even some unstable random values because of metastability issues.

Comment: Thank you so much.